# integer value will not be changed by method

Tags: ios, objective-c, integer

Maybe someone can clarify this for me.

I have 4 UITableViewControllers, the first one has a property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int editStarted;
```

I set this property in FirstViewController:

```
-(id)init
{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {

    editStarted = 0; // NO
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now when I navigate from view controller 1 to 2 to 3 to 4, and do something like this in FourthViewController:

```
FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"editStarted: %d,",firstView.editStarted);
```

NSLOG will print 0. (and if I give it another value in init then it will print that value.)

So back in FirstViewController I do this, to change the value to 1:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 editStarted = 1;
}
```

Now when I navigate from view controller 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 the value has not changed to 1 but is still 0.

Is this standard behavior or am I doing something wrong? 
I have thought of the possibility to pass `editStarted` from view controller 1 to 2 to 3 to 4, but I am not sure if that is the right way. It sounds a bit redundant to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
```

Creates a new instance of the same class as VC 1. But it isn't the same instance that you saw originally, so it has different settings.

You should use the navigation controller to get the 'real' VC 1 and log its settings.

---

Passing variables from one VC to the next is a standard approach, but it depends what you're trying to do. In some cases it could be better to set a value into `NSUserDefaults` for example so that it can be checked / used / changed from multiple different screens.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense! thank you. And by using the navigation controller you mean the appDelegate.m, the one where I define "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
" etc?

Comment: And just for your information, I want to go from view controller 1 to 4 and when I am in 4, i want to show data from 2 to 4 in VC1. I use 2 to 4 to make a specific selection.

Comment: In a VC, `self.navigationController` will get you to the nav controller. Delegate relationship is appropriate for passing selection data back from 2, 3 & 4 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

you Creates a new instance of the same class so its assign the new memory thats why all the times its shown zero.

so you have better option to assign the object of parent class to the child class /

otherwise make object of class only once ...